# Looking for recommendation for Software Deployment Tool

Tags: windows, c#, .net, remote-access

I have a piece of software which is built in c#.Net and uses MS Sql Server as a database back end. It is currently installed on around 100 Windows Pc's and growing. I am looking to see if anyone had any recommendation on a Software Deployment Tool which would let me manage and upgrade these devices better than the current manual process of using Teamviewer to File Transfer and Copy over New EXE Files onto each client machine.

It would also be good to be able to deal with any Scripted needed on the remote SQL Databases and perhaps query them without interfering with the operation of these devices as most of them are in use on a regular basis ?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [VSTS Release Management](https://vsts-deploy-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to Deploy and manage your software.

Later you can add a task, **Windows Machine Copy**, to transfer the file to the client machine in the task group of your deployment. You can also add a task, **Powershell task** to run any script in the remote machine. This is pretty handy in terms of automated deployment. Hope this answers your query.

Comment: I was looking for someone more like Remote Access to the 100 Devices to mass copy Upgrade files etc.. this is more for Domain admin's in a Local Network I think. But thanks